# Fortran transpose of matrix doesn't work on non-2D arrays

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran, matrix-multiplication

Say I have a 3D array, `A(1:3,1:4,1:5)`, and I only want to deal with part of it, e.g.:

```
real :: A(1:3,1:4,1:5), B(1:5,1:2)
real, allocatable :: C(:,:)

allocate(C(size(A,1),size(B,2)))
C = matmul(A(1:3,1,1:5),B)
```

Fortran seems fine with that. However, if I needed to deal with the transpose, then the `transpose` function in Fortran gets confused, e.g.:

```
real :: A(1:3,1:4,1:5), B(1:3,1:2)
real, allocatable :: C(:,:)

allocate(C(size(A,3),size(B,2)))
C = matmul(transpose(A(1:3,1,1:5)),B)
```

How can I swap dimensions around in an array with Fortran? For example, I have A(3,4,5); is there a function/command that takes this and gives me A(5,4,3) or A(4,3,5) or any arrangement I could wish for? Without, of course, doing something like copying A to a dummy array with the dimensions in the order required. I'm looking for a simple one line elegant way.

Thank you.

Comment: When your array indices start from 1, you can just write the upper bound at declaration time, e.g. A(3,4,5), because indexing is by default from 1 in Fortran. It might be easier to spot mistakes like this. Also, when you slice through the whole dimension, you can just do A(:,1,:) instead of A(1:3,1,1:5).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have a problem with `TRANSPOSE`. It is working just fine for the sample code you provided. The problem is that your arrays are not compatible for matrix multiplication. From Fortran 2008 Standard draft:

> Case (i): If MATRIX A has shape [n, m] and MATRIX B has shape [m, k],
>   the result has shape [n, k].

In your case:

```
C = matmul(transpose(A(1:3,1,1:5)),B)
```

Here, `transpose(A(1:3,1,1:5))` is a 5x3 matrix, and B is 2x5. Thus, these two matrices are non-comformable for `MATMUL`. I am wondering how you did not catch on this since compilers give a clear error message:

gfortran 4.1.2:

```
In file matrix.f90:13

C = matmul(transpose(A(:,1,:)),B)
          1
Error: different shape on dimension 2 for argument 'matrix_a' and dimension 1 for argument 'matrix_b' at (1) for intrinsic matmul
```

ifort 12.0.2.137:

```
matrix.f90(13): error #6241: The shapes of the arguments are inconsistent or nonconformable.   [MATMUL]
C = matmul(transpose(A(:,1,:)),B)
----^
compilation aborted for matrix.f90 (code 1)
```

pgf90 10.6-0 compiles but produces a run-time error:

```
0: MATMUL: nonconforming array shapes
```

For reshaping arrays in Fortran, you can use intrinsic function `RESHAPE`. From Fortran 2008 Standard draft:

> 13.7.140 RESHAPE (SOURCE, SHAPE [, PAD, ORDER])
>
> 1 Description. Construct an array of an arbitrary shape.
>
> 2 Class. Transformational
>   function.
>
> 3 Arguments. SOURCE shall be an array of any type. If PAD is
>   absent or of size zero, the size of SOURCE shall be greater
>         than or equal to PRODUCT (SHAPE). The size of the result is the product of the values of the
>        elements of SHAPE. SHAPE shall be a rank-one integer array. SIZE (x), where x is the actual argument corresponding to
>        SHAPE, shall be a constant expression whose value is positive and less than 16. It shall not have
>       an element whose value is negative. PAD (optional) shall be an array of the same type and type parameters as SOURCE. ORDER (optional)
>   shall be of type integer, shall have the same shape as SHAPE, and its
>   value shall be a permutation of (1, 2, . . . , n), where n is the size
>   of SHAPE. If absent, it is as if it were present with value (1, 2, . .
>   . , n).
>
> 4 Result Characteristics. The result is an array of shape
>   SHAPE (that is, SHAPE (RESHAPE (SOURCE, SHAPE, PAD, ORDER)) is equal
>   to SHAPE) with the same type and type parameters as SOURCE.
>
> 5 Result
>   Value. The elements of the result, taken in permuted subscript order
>   ORDER (1), . . . , ORDER (n), are those of SOURCE in normal array
>   element order followed if necessary by those of PAD in array element
>   order, followed if necessary by additional copies of PAD in array
>   element order.

Comment: Sorry about that. It has been corrected now. It was not wrong in my code. Are you saying once this has been rectified the code should run fine? It compiles, but exits with code 02.

Comment: @SamuelTan Yes. You now have A (3x5) with B(3,2) so MATMUL of A transposed (5x3) with B gives you C of shape (5x2). Your program works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

A(1:3,1,1:5) is a rank-two array of size 3 x 5.  By specifying a specific value (1) for the second index of the rank-three array "A" rather than a range you have reduced the dimensionality.  transpose of A(1:3,1,1:5) should be a rank-two array of size 5 x 3.

If you want to make an arbitrary change in the dimensions of an array use the "reshape" intrinsic function.  Whether it will place the elements where you want them is another question.    Usage example: `A = reshape (A, [5,4,3])`.

Comment: So you're saying that for `A(i,j,k)`, `A(k,j,i) = reshape(A, [k,j,i])`, `A(j,k,i) = reshape(A,[j,k,i])` etc... just use reshape to move the indices of the dimensions around?

Comment: `[5,4,3]` is the shape the new `A`, I see. You're not sure how the elements are filled in to the new array. I think this should work: `reshape(A,[5,4,3], [3,2,1]))` where `[3,2,1]` is the order of dimensions as the elements are filled in. Learnt that from http://www.nsc.liu.se/~boein/f77to90/a5.html. Very useful page I found. Please correct me if I'm wrong.